# MS Access SQL how to display the unique result

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am new with the MS access SQL and the following is what I would like to do
in my database table

I have the following data

[image]

basically no duplicate, I tried "Distinct" but given my result is not one column only so I can't do that. I research online and look like it might need to use inner join but I only have one table only.

Appreciate if anyone can help me up..
Thanks

Regards,
Marc

Comment: please show your query

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or links to images...)

Comment: The question is rather - why do you store same persons birthday several times? Tip of today: Primary keys (or UNIQUE constraints.)

Comment: Normalize your data. Customers and Purchases must be two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, birthday
FROM [table];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
from TABLENAME;
```

Replace columns and table name with respective values.

like this

```
select DISTINCT name, birthday from TABLENAME;
```